# Bootstrap Upgrade Appears to have cause Odd Positioning issue with Datatables Search Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, alignment

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC project which requires a plethora of frontend javascript libraries, and not all of them seem to play nicely together.

One of my teammates upgraded our project from Twitter Bootstrap v2.X to v3.3.5 over a weekend, and our [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) now have an awkward issue where the search fiter is displayed on the left side of another row, even though the sDom I've specified clearly indicates that it should be displayed in the first row and ideally aligned to the right.

```
var sDomGrid = '<"row" <l><f><r>>t<"row" <i><p>>';
```

Previously, the sDom looked like this:

```
var sDomGrid = "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>";
```

In either case, the DataTable search filter displays like this:
[image]

I inferred that this was most likely caused by the Bootstrap upgrade, and so I updated JQuery UI to 1.11.4, which shipped with an updated JQuery 1.11.3, and I also updated DataTables itself to 1.10.9. Interestingly, pretty much nothing changed concerning my search filter. In fact, almost **nothing I do** to the sDom seems to alter the datatable header at all.

I've tried clearing all caches, inspecting the element in developer's console within Chrome to spot troublesome css, javascript debugging to see if this is being overwritten at some point, and nearly exhausted the internet and not found anyone with a similar issue.

Has anyone else experienced this or a similar issue, and what advice or troubleshooting steps could you direct me to next?

Comment: You must be more specific, i.e create a fiddle that reproduces the behavior. `dom :'<"row" <l><f><r>>t<"row" <i><p>>'` does **not** align the searchbox to the left, and bootstrap 3.3.5 does not move dataTables dynamically created controls around.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 requires specific string in [`dom`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option, see [Styling](http://datatables.net/reference/option/dom#Styling) section for more details.

> The styling libraries that DataTables supports will override the default value of the `dom` parameter and replace it with a value that is suitable for their layout system. For example the Bootstrap integration makes use of Bootstrap's grid layout.
>
> The defaults for the styling integrations are:
>
> Bootstrap:
>
> ```js
> "dom": "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>>" +
>        "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
>        "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>"
> ```